# Cant display the csv data in a seperate file in django

Tags: django, csv

I am trying to display some csv(comma seperated values) in my project. So I have a html button click upon which a django view function is called through JavaScript. This is my django view function :

```
def make_csv(request):
    testdata = "[{\"severity\":\"0\",\"description\":\"USB Connected\",\"date\":\"01/01/2015\",\"time\":\"11:35:20\"},{\"severity\":\"3\",\"description\":\"USB Disconnected\",\"date\":\"01/01/2015\",\"time\":\"10:30:19\"}]";
    data = json.loads(testdata)
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="eventlog.csv"'

    writer = csv.writer(response,csv.excel)
    writer.writerow(data[0].keys())
    for row in data:
        writer.writerow(row.values())
    return response
```

But I can't get any file displayed in my browser. Also I can see the values returned using my JavaScript. Is there a way to display the result as a seperate file in the browser so that users can download it?

Comment: How about adding a normal `a` link instead of a click event on your button, maybe with a `target="_blank"` attribute to point to that URL?

Comment: the problem is that i cannot return the result as a file from the view

Comment: What happens if you manually open the URL that you now request through Javascript?

Comment: I can get the file that way

Comment: Then what you have isn't a Django problem, but a file handling problem - check this post out, it has a bunch of ideas on your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16086162/handle-file-download-from-ajax-post

Comment: Like Andrei says, use an anchor instead of a JavaScript event.